# excel: formula with brackets or whitespace

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I experience that excel/vba does not like formulas containing brackets or whitespaces.

This works:

```
currShart.SeriesCollection(count).XValues = "=FITC!$A$2:$A$701"
```

But these do not work

```
.XValues = "=FITC(a)!$A$2:$A$701"
.XValues = "=FITC a!$A$2:$A$701"
.XValues = "="FITC a"!$A$2:$A$701"
```

I do however have sheets with such names. How can I insert these formulars?

Comment: try `"='FITC a'!$A$2:$A$701"`

Comment: @mehow: I don't know if it can be termed as programming question. You can add that as an answer.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it could have been worded differently, but it's an excel related question

Comment: @mehow: I am sorry, I didn't get your comments. I meant to say, you can add the answer instead of a comment. Unfortunately, it isn't a programming related q. It is indeed an Excel related q.

Comment: @shahkalpesh ok. The question was a bit unclear as I wasn't sure where the expression is being used. I wanted to OP to try and give feedback. It's never too late to [promote a comment an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers).

Comment: @mehow: It works that way. You may add an answer.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech OK. done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use sheet names which include spaces use

`'` name with space `'`

example:

```
"='FITC a'!$A$2:$A$701"
```